# Conversion between decimals and % fails if we follow the conventional wisdome of the percentage change vs. percentage point?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I am not a mathematician but have some theoretical question.

To refer to probability, we can use either decimals (e.g., 0.1) or a percentage (e.g., 10%), because % means "multiply with 1/100", right? (And probability here does not necessarily mean the frequency but also includes a scale of subjective confidence as in Bayesian statistics).

If so, we should be able to say both:

- "The probability increased from 0.1 to 0.15, or by 0.05."
- "The probability increased from 10% to 15%, or by 5%."

and these two sentences should be interchangeable.

However, in the standard math explanation, the second sentence should be written as:

- "The probability increased from 10% to 15%, or by 5 percentage points."

because % is a relative measure so that an absolute difference should be expressed as a percentage point. But in the decimal format, none of the three numbers (0.1, 0.15, and 0.05) needs not be distinguished from one another by different units (right?). Then, it seems inconsistent to apply two different units (% and percentage points) once we multiply these decimals by 100.

The standard math explanation also says that if we use a % unit to describe the difference, we should write:

- "The probability increased from 10% to 15%, or by 50%."

because % is a relative measure. But then, if % simply means "multiply with 1/100" and we remove the symbol from the above sentence, it does not convert back to the original sentence, "The probability increased from 0.1 to 0.15, or by 0.05" but will become "The probability increased from 0.1 to 0.15, or by 0.50".

Is my reasoning flawed in some way?

Comment: When talking about percentages or percentage points, it must be made clear what the percentages *are of*.  The probability increased from $10\%$ to $15\%$, that is it increased by $5\%$ **of the probability of the sure event**.  Versus, The probability increased from $10\%$ to $15\%$, that is increased by $50\%$ **of the probability of the original event**.  These are different sentences.  The confusion is that it is ambiguous what percentages are taken relative to if you aren't explicit.  You should always be explicit when possible.

Comment: I agree. Talking about percentage changes in quantities that are themselves percentages is perfectly mathematically sound, but it's extremely easy to be ambiguous.

Comment: And a $50\%$ increase in the chance of the event occurring means that the you've increased that probability by half, which is also true. Percentage point differences and percent changes are different measurements, that's why the numbers are different, not because the rule doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you all. @JMoravitz I don't understand why the probability of a sure event can change, as it is by definition 1.

Comment: @Amaan I understand they are different measurements, but why do we use these difference measurements for numbers in the same scale (probability)? i.e. why in decimals both probabilities and probability differences are just raw numbers (which implies they are in the same measurement) but when multiplied by 100 the probabilities are in % while the probability differences are in percentage points? I know the practical reason for avoiding confusion but theoretically it looks inconsistent to me.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: I never said the probability of a sure event could change.  I said the *other* probability could change by an amount *proportional to the probability of the sure event*

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: They're not the same scale. Percent change is not a probability. It's the percent change in the probability. The probability ranges from 0% to 100%. Percent change has a range of -100% to $\infty$. They're measuring different things, that's why they're different numbers.

Comment: @AmaaM Thanks; I was talking about percentage points (pp). Let me elaborate. "The length increased from 10cm to 15cm, or by 5cm" is 15cm-10cm=5cm. Because they are in the same scale, the formula can reduce to 15-10=5. If "The length increased from 10cm to 15cm, or by 50mm", 15cm-10cm=50mm which cannot reduce to 15-10=50 since cm and mm are difference units. "The probability increased from 10% to 15%, or by 5%" should then be 15%-10%=5% but if we follow the standard math explanation, it is 15%-10%=5pp. i.e. % seems to me more theoretically consistent than pp to describe probability difference.

Comment: I'm not challenging the formulae behind computing probability difference or probability change. I am just finding a little ad hoc the ways that the different units are used.